# Function using iterators to perform a object operation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator, containers

Assuming I have an `std::array<SomeType, N>` and I'd like to call a function which uses iterators to work with the objects in the `std::array` but without knowing about the container being a `std::array`.

SomeType is a class which has a public member function doSomething()

For example a function might be:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void action(Iterator &beg, Iterator &end) {
  for (; beg != end; ++beg)
    beg->doSomething();
}
```

Calling this function is possible by:

```
int main() {
  std::array<SomeType, 10> a;

  action<std::array<SomeType, 10>::iterator>(a.begin(), a.end());
}
```

But I'm wondering if this is the way to do it? Especially because the template could be used for each class. Is there a way to restrict the function to `SomeType` without letting the function know that the container is an `std::array`?

Comment: The code as written does not compile. At least it is not well-formed C++. [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tw8f7mpNxZTZel9X)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Fix your code: You should not require lvalue arguments. In fact, iterators are meant to be copyable efficiently.

   ```
   template<typename Iterator>
   void action(Iterator beg, Iterator end)
   //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. Let template argument deduction do its job:

   ```
   action(a.begin(), a.end());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the standard library already has a number of algorithms that cover the general case of "doing the same thing over some range in some container":

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

struct SomeType
{
  void doSomething();

  SomeType mutatedCopy() const;

  int someValue() const;
};

int add_value(int i, const SomeType& st) {
  return i + st.someValue();
}

void call_something(SomeType& st) { st.doSomething(); }
auto mutate_copy(SomeType const& st) { return st.mutatedCopy(); }

int main() {
  std::array<SomeType, 10> a;
  std::vector<SomeType> b;

  std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), call_something);
  std::for_each(b.begin(), b.end(), call_something);

  std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), mutate_copy);
  std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), b.begin(), mutate_copy);

  auto tot = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0, add_value)
           + std::accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), 0, add_value);

  // you can even transform into dissimilar containers:

  std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), mutate_copy);

}
```